# Could a ZIP be 100% OK but be unzipped with errors?

Tags: 7-zip

Last night, I unzipped several zip files with 7-Zip and one of them that I tried turned out to have faulty content, BUT the ZIP file tested OK, and what's more, when I unzipped it again for the second time, the content was fine.

Could there sometimes be errors in data after being unzipped from intact ZIP files, and is there any way to detect them?

Comment: in practise(and to a large extent in theory too I suppose), an error in a file within a zip, is independent of an error within a zip.  (though it's possible in theory for a zip file to get corrupted in such a way that the zip doesn't show as corrupted and a file within it gets changed, I think it's very unlikely).. The proper way to test for corruption would be with an MD5 check then you'll know for sure if the zip is corrupt or if any individual file is corrupt.

Comment: also if you're talking about an error within a file within a zip, you probably shouldn't really be asking about whether a zip is ok or not.  And as for why I suppose if the file unzipped ok one time and not another then maybe as an answered said, an IO error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I unzipped it again for the second time, the content was fine.

That could be anything e.g. a temporary I/O error on your disc. If you succeeded to unzip second time then the zip is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently something went wrong during the unzip process. It was likely terminated prematurely.

Although a problem on your harddisk could in theory produce this, it is unlikely.

The fact that the ZIP file itself unzipped correctly the second time indicates the ZIP is fine.